# Quiet `bash: ${PS1@P}: bad substitution` message

Tags: bash

On older versions of bash, some variable / parameter expansions don't exist.

An example is expanding a variable as a prompt string:

```
echo ${PS1@P}
```

On an older version of bash, even if I do:

```
$ echo "${PS1@P}" &> /dev/null
```

I still see:

```
bash: ${PS1@P}: bad substitution
```

Note that both STDOUT and STDERR were redirected above.

How do I silently expand a parameter and check if it worked?

Comment: The redirection only applies to the `echo` command itself, but the bad substitution occurs *before* `echo` is executed.

Answer (score 2):

Redirecting STDERR works when using `eval`:

```
eval 'str="${PS1@P}";' 2>/dev/null || echo fail
```

At this point, either you'll see `fail` or the variable `$str` will contain the expansion of the prompt.

**Notes:**

As `@Charles Duffy` points out in the comments, surrounding in `{` `}` will abort on failure without printing `fail` in `bash 4.3.48`.

The other option is to use a subshell.

Comment: There's no compelling need for `eval` here; braces will suffice: `{ str=${PS1@P}; } 2>/dev/null`

Comment: You could also check `BASH_VERSION` (or `BASH_VERSINFO`) before trying to expand.

Comment: (Caveat, on testing: On some versions of bash, the syntax error will abort the larger conditional statement *unless* one moves from a regular brace group to a subshell).

Comment: Cheers... back to the doubly-quoted eval then :)

Comment: Re: subshell -- `str=$(printf '%s\n' "${PS1@P}") 2>/dev/null` smuggles your desired value out on stdout.